# How to set unique ID with ID of group in it?

Tags: sql

I have this table:

| ID | Value | Gr_Id | Gr_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | A | 1 | A |
| NULL | B | 1 | A |
| NULL | C | 2 | B |
| NULL | D | 2 | B |
| NULL | E | 2 | B |
| NULL | F | 3 | C |

And I need id like this

| ID | Value | Gr_Id | Gr_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | A | 1 | A |
| 102 | B | 1 | A |
| 201 | C | 2 | B |
| 202 | D | 2 | B |
| 203 | E | 2 | B |
| 301 | F | 3 | C |

I need unique ID for each row but with ID of group on beginning

Comment: What is your database? Provide your type of database. You can regenerate the data? What about the new values you will insert?

Comment: which db are you using?

Comment: What if you have more than 99 distinct value for any of the ID group ? What should be rule then ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

if maximum number per group is 99 then :

```
select gr_id * 100 + row_number() over (partition by Gr_id order by gr_value) as Id , *
from tablename
```